# `This cup hadn't been drunk out of for...` vs `This cup wasn't being drunk out of for...`

Tags: past-tense

Is sentence "This cup hadn't been drunk out of for twenty years precisely since its owner was exiled to Siberia." right?

I suppose no because it's not about up until point in past.

I think the right form is "This cup wasn't being drunk out of for twenty years precisely since its owner was exiled to Siberia."

Comment: Do you mean the cups owner was exiled to Siberia 20 year before the present. Is "exile to Sibera" still a thing in 21st century Russia? It sounds very Stalinist.

Comment: Do you mean the cups owner was exiled to Siberia 20 year before the present. - yes. Is "exile to Sibera" still a thing in 21st century Russia? - hah no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The past perfect is grammatically correct but may not be the meaning you intend.

Similarly the past continuous is grammatical, but the meaning is a little odd. It also means "for a period of time in the past". If you mean "for a period of time until the present" you should normally use the present perfect:

> This cup hasn't been drunk out of for twenty years...

It may well be better to rephrase in the active voice

> Nobody has drunk out of this cup for twenty years...

Comment: Ok, present perfect is the best. Also I think I understand why past perfect is fine too - speaker means "for a period of time until the past (e.g. someone drunk from cup 1 week ago)"

Comment: @srghma That's right.